# Identify a numbers game where you strike out numbers

Tags: identify-this-game

In this game you start out by jotting down numbers 1 through 19 on a squared paper into 9 columns (and skip 10, there are no zeroes).

[image: Numbers game starting point]

Then you start striking out numbers that are adjacent (diagonally doesn't count) and are the same numbers or have a sum of ten. Also, the struck out numbers don't count either, for example, if you have 4 <s>5</s> 6, then you can strike out 4 and 6 (their sum is 10).

[image: Numbers game strike out]

If you have struck out all the pairs you can find, you write the left over numbers again and look for new pairs. You win if you've struck out all the numbers.

[image: Numbers game continued]

My question is - does this game have an actual name or is it "that numbers game that everyone played in high school"?

Comment: Is it the same numbers every time? Seems like the replay value would be minimal if it didn't change.

Comment: Yes, the numbers are same. It's not really meant to be a real puzzle, just something to pass the time with.

Comment: You start with an odd number of digits and cross out digits in pairs. When you write out all the remaining digits do you then have to get rid of both sets of digits?

Comment: Well, the game can conceivably go on forever, I you can't get rid of all the numbers. You just keep on writing out the remaining numbers when you can't find any more matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only thing I've been able to find refers to the game as TenPair

http://www.logicgamesonline.com/tenpair/

Comment: Yes, that's the same game. I guess "TenPair" is as good a name as any.

Answer (score 2):

The game is widely known as Numberama. I found it on the google play store(android) and enjoy it a lot. 
It's also referred to as Digits, Numbers Game and TenPair.

It can be played traditionally using the digits of the numbers from 1-19, or using randomized digits.